# How does the main method work?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I'm the product of some broken teaching and I need some help. I know that there is this thing called the "main method" in Java and I'm sure other programming languages. I know that you need one to make your code run, but how do you use it to make your run? What does it do and what do you need to have it put in it to make your code run?

I know it should look something like this.
But almost nothing more.

```
static void main(String[] args){

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public static void main(String[] args){...}`

Comment: can it ever be private?

Comment: What do you mean by "how does it work?" Have you read the relevant part of the Java Tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN

Comment: Java Tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/ is a good starting point to answer your own questions about Java.

Comment: @MadProgrammer You should really make it an answer.

Comment: jvm searches all public class's public method for main with same signature, Its predefined entry point for all java applications.J2EE applications,android apps do have entry point but you are not supposed to define that, since it is already configured.

Comment: `The method MUST be public and it must exist within a public class` - The main method does ***not*** need to be in a public class in order to be found and run.

Comment: @Perception Live and learn.  Although it does seem counter intuitive, but what do I know ;)

Comment: If you want the JVM to be able to execute it, no. The method MUST be public

Comment: @MadProgrammer - a day without learning something new is a day wasted!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Breaking this down, point-by-point, for the general case:

1. All Java applications begin processing with a `main()` method;
2. Each statement in the `main` executes in order until the end of `main` is reached -- this is when your program terminates;
3. What does `static` mean? `static` means that you don't have to instantiate a class to call the method;
4. `String[]` args is an array of `String` objects. If you were to run your program on the command line, you could pass in parameters as arguments. These parameters can then be accessed as you would access elements in an array: `args[0]...args[n]`;
5. `public` means that the method can be called by any object.

Comment: (main method can exit, but the application may not terminate - termination occurs when all non-daemon threads exit - nit pick to be sure ;))

Answer (score 2):

its the entry point for any java program, it does whatever you tell it to do. all you need to do is declare it in one of your source java files and the compiler will find it.

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

`void` means the method returns no value. `String[] args` represents a string of arguments  in an Array type that are passed to the program. `main` is the single point of entry in to most Java programs.

### Extended

Glossing over why it should be `public static void...` (You wouldn't build a door without a doorknob), methods (equivalent of functions (or subs) in other languages) in Java have a return type. It just so happens that the `main` method in Java has to return void. In C or C++, the main method can `return` an `int` and usually this indicates the code status of the finished program. An `int` value of `0` is the standard for a successful completion.

To get the same effect in Java, we use `System.exit(intValue)`

`String[] args` is a string array of arguments, passed to the main function, usually for specific application use. Usually these are used to modify a default behavior or for flags used in short command line executable applications.

`main` just means to the JVM, start here! Same name in C and C++ (and probably more).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it should be `public static void main(String[] args){...}`.

It must be `public`

Take a look at [The main method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN)

The JVM will look for this method signature when it runs you class...

```
java helloWorld.HelloWorld
```

It represents the entry point for your application.  You should put all the required initialization code here that is required to get your application running.

The following is a simple example (which can be executed with the command from above)

```
package helloWorld;

public class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you need to "get your application running"?

Comment: The class containing the main method does not need to be public. The example you linked actually shows a main method in a class with package access.

Comment: @Perception Yep picked that up :D

Comment: @Throsby Copy the code.  Make a directory called `helloWorld`, create a file called `HelloWorldApp` and copy the contents into, save the file.  At the commend line, change to the directory containing the `helloWorld` directory and use the `javac` to compile it...`javac helloWorld\helloWorld.java`.  Once compiled, you can run it from the same location using `java helloWorld.HelloWorld`.  Ideally, save yourself some trouble and get a decent IDE instead

Answer (score 1):

when you execute your class, anything in the main method runs.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a **main class** and a **main method**. And if you want to find something in the console, you need have one output command at least in the method, like :

*System.out.println("Hello World!");*

This makes the code running **lively**.