# Telephone Word generator java program

Tags: java

I was trying to write a java program that would convert a telephone number into different combinations of words.

> Many people find it difficult to memorize phone numbers so they use
>   the correspondence between digits and letters to develop seven-letter
>   words that correspond to their phone numbers.  For example, a person
>   whose telephone number is 686-2377 might use the correspondence
>   indicated in Figure Telephone keypad digits and letters to develop the
>   seven-letter word “NUMBERS.”  Every seven-letter word corresponds to
>   exactly one seven-digit telephone number. Every seven-letter phone
>   number corresponds to many different seven-letter words, but most of
>   these words represent unrecognizable juxtapositions of letters. Write
>   a program that, given a seven-digit number supplied by the user, uses
>   a PrintStream object to write to a file every possible seven-letter
>   word combination corresponding to that number. There are 2,187 (3^7)
>   such combinations.  Avoid phone numbers with the digits 0 and 1.

In the program I am having problems with the main method. Is it wrong or I am putting it in the wrong place?

Here is my program:

```
public class TelephoneNumberWordGenerator

{

    String phoneNumber;
    char numberLetters[][] = {
            {'0','0','0'},{'1','1','1'},{'A','B','C'},
            {'D','E','F'},{'G','H','I'},{'J','K','L'},
            {'M','N','O'},{'P','R','S'},
            {'T','U','V'},{'W','X','Y'}};


    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    PrintStream printStream;
    char[] word = new char [7];


    public static void main(String[] args){
    public void getPhoneNumber(){
            System.out.println("Enter a seven-digit telephone number: ");
            phoneNumber = input.next();

        }
    }

    public void openFile()
    {
        try // open file
        {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream ( "Phonenumber.txt") );

        }// end try
        catch ( IOException ioEcception )
        {
            System.err.println( "Error opening file.");
        } // end catch
    }// end method open file

    public void addFileInfo( )
    {
        try
        {
            char[] chars = phoneNumber.toCharArray ();
            int [] digit = new int [chars.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
            {
                digit[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(chars[i]));
            }

            printStream = new PrintStream(output);
            printStream.println("\n");


            for ( int level0 = 0; level0 < 3; level0 ++ )
            {
                word[0] = numberLetters[digit[0]][level0];

                for ( int level1 = 0; level1 < 3; level1 ++ )
                {
                    word[1] = numberLetters[digit[1]][level1];

                    for ( int level2 = 0; level2 < 3; level2 ++ )
                    {
                        word[2] = numberLetters[digit[2]][level2];

                        for ( int level3 = 0; level3 < 3; level3 ++ )
                        {
                            word[3] = numberLetters[digit[3]][level3];

                            for ( int level4 = 0; level4 < 3; level4 ++ )
                            {
                                word[4] = numberLetters[digit[4]][level4];

                                for ( int level5 = 0; level5 < 3; level5 ++ )
                                {
                                    word[5] = numberLetters[digit[5]][level5];

                                    for ( int level6 = 0; level6 < 3; level6 ++ )
                                    {
                                        word[6] = numberLetters[digit[6]][level6];
                                        printStream.print(word);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("File written.");
            System.exit(1);

        }
        catch (Exception exception )
        {
            System.err.println( "Error writing to file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void closeFile()
    {
        try // close file
        {
            if ( output != null )
                output.close();
        }// end try
        catch (IOException ioException )
        {
            System.err.println( "Error closing file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }// end catch


    }// end method closeFile
}
```

Comment: Your main method is inside another method, `getPhoneNumber()`. Get it out of there.

Comment: Indent you code, it looks horrible...

Comment: Yeah. The `main` method is it's own methods. You put it inside another method. How are you not getting a compiler error from this?

Comment: As a side note, XKCD already did something very close http://whatif.xkcd.com/75/

Comment: I don't understand why people often try to implement some of those let's call it "more difficult" stuff without having understood the basics of the program language.

Comment: I indented your code for you. It makes it much easier to read. Also, it means it's unnecessary to include `// End of method foo` comments at each bracket, because you can just look at the indentation to see where they correspond. Most IDE's already do this. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Quirliom I could not find anything from the site you mentioned and I am using Eclipse as my IDE. Also I do get compilation error but I do not know where do I put my main method in the program.

Comment: You put it wherever you want. What happens is when your program is launched, the system calls your `main` method. So that is where the program starts. From the `main` method you can call other methods, create objects, and all sorts of stuff. Other than the fact that the system calls it at the beginning, it's just like any other method. What is your confusion with the main method _exactly_?

Comment: Also, Eclipse should correct your indentation as you go, unless you turned that feature off. I know it works with mine. What you can do in Eclipse is select the code, right click, and go Source > Correct Indentation. It should do the same thing I did above, which is indent the code to make it much more readable.

Comment: I changed my program little bit and added main method outside the getPhonenumber() method and it is still giving me errors. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well now your `getPhoneNumber()` method is inside your `main` method. Same problem. *In Java you cannot have methods inside other methods.* **Ever.** You can call the `getPhoneNumber()` method from your `main`, but you can't put it inside the method itself.

Comment: when I try to do that it gives me many errors

Comment: I have added private ObjectOutputStream in the main method and it says that it cannot start with private

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962535/how-does-the-main-method-work) for more information on how the main method works. From what you've said above, you don't seem to understand exactly what it does, or what it is. Once you've read those, let me know that you don't understand, if any, and we can discuss it at length until we've figured it out. In your reply, please type "@AndrewG" so the site lets me know that you've replied. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a method getPhoneNumber() inside your main method which is incorrect in java.
Define it outside the main method and call it inside main()

Answer (score 0):

## For people looking for solution in Javascript, here is a recursive solution. for other languages, please convert the code

```
const group = [];
result = [];
let numstr = "";
var letterCombinations = function(num) {
  numstr = num.toString();
  const letters = [,,['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k','l'],['m','n','o'],['p','q','r','s'],['t','u','v'],['w','x','y','z']];
  for (let i=0; i<numstr.length; i++) {
    group.push(letters[parseInt(numstr[i])]);
  }
  wordMaker(num, 0, "");
  return result;
}

const wordMaker = (num, n, w) => {
  for (let i=0; i<group[n].length; i++) {
    if (n === group.length-1) {
      result.push(w + group[n][i])
    }
    else {
      wordMaker(num, n+1, w + group[n][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Test Input

```
console.log(letterCombinations(23));
```

#### Output

```
[ 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem has to be the main method inside another method. In java you can't write the code for methods inside other methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        TelephoneNumberWordGenerator tt=new TelephoneNumberWordGenerator();

                System.out.println("Enter a seven-digit telephone number: ");
                phoneNumber = input.next();
                tt.openFile();
                tt.addFileInfo();
                tt.closeFile();

           }
```