# Main method not found in class Television, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

This program must print final parametres about a TV state in three (3) rows...
in first row...on which level loudness is...
in the second on which program is (1., 2., 56, etc...)
third row - is it turned on...

(after all operations inside programm)... this programm is pasted from manual for Java...

```
class Television {
    int volumeTone = 0;
    int channelNow = 1;
    boolean turnedOn = false;

    void turnOn(){
        turnedOn = true;
    }
    void turnOff(){
        turnedOn = false;
    }
    void increaseVolume(){
        volumeTone = volumeTone + 1;
    }
    void decreaseVolume(){
        volumeTone = volumeTone - 1;
    }
    void turnOffVolume(){
        volumeTone = 0;
     }
    void changeChannelUp(){
        channelNow = channelNow + 1;
     }
    void changeChannelDown(){
        channelNow = channelNow - 1;
     }
    int returnChannelBefore(){
    return channelNow;
     }
    int returnToneVolume(){
        return volumeTone;
     }
    boolean isItTurnedOn(){
        return turnedOn;
     }
    void writeParametres(){
       System.out.println("Volume loudness now is "+volumeTone);
       System.out.println("Channel now is "+channelNow);
       System.out.println("Tv is turned on? "+turnedOn);

    }
}
```

Comment: Poor English; question unclear.

Comment: The question is not clear you need to give more of a description of what you want to do. The wording of the question is not easily understandable. If you want to run the code then you need to tell/try to say what how you want to run it. Also the error fully explains your problem in this case, and that's you need to write the method (main) in to be able to run this class.

Comment: You only define `main` method in the class that is suppose to run on it's own or application root. You don't have to have `main` method in **every** class as you are not meant to run them on their own, they are part of the bigger system.

Comment: Take a look at this link: [The Java Main method](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a main method in the class to run...

Answer (score 0):

Your exception itself say that, `please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)`
You need `main` method in your class `Television` as shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
   //Your logic run this class
}
```

In Java, you need to have a method named `main` in at least one class.
[Please refer this link](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html) about main method.

Answer (score 0):

Without a main method, you will not be able to run anything. Create a new class with a main method like so:

```
public class myClass
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
                //Here you can create an instance of your television class                  
                Television tel = new Television();

                //You can then call methods on your newly created instance
                tel.turnOn();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main entrance to a java application is with a static main method
which is usually defined as;

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
}
```

If you want to run any class make sure it has this method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Implement main method

Answer (score 0):

From [The Java Tutorials' **Hello World** Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter#MAIN): (emphasis mine)

> In the Java programming language, **every application must contain a main method** whose signature is: `public static void main(String[] args)`
>
> ...
>
> The main method is similar to the main function in C and C++; **it's the entry point for your application** and will subsequently invoke all the other methods required by your program.

In other words, when running a Java class, the JVM will look for a `main()` method in it. That method will be called automatically when running the class, and will be the *entry point* for the execution flow of the program.

Also, take a look at [How does the main method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15962535).