# no main manifest attribute

Tags: jar, attributes, export, manifest

Any .jar file I export from eclipse does not work. I keep on receiving the "no main manifest attribute" error when I try to run the .jar file from command prompt. 
When I try and double click the .jar file it does not run. Exporting the file itself is simple, there are plenty of tutorials for this, but the .jar wont run.

Is there a step by step solution to this problem for beginners? I looked through different forums but I do not undertstand how to fix it. I export a class called "test2.java" under the name "hello"

Comment: Did you select "Runnable JAR" in the first eclipse screen when exporting? I'm hoping your class actually has a main method.

Comment: I did both, the runnable JAR and JAR options. I think that might be the problem, Im not sure what a main method is?   
Up till now ive been coding simple excercises and doing assignments from the cs106a stanford course, so a complete beginner.

Comment: Please refer the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962535/how-does-the-main-method-work). It's one of the first concepts you should learn when beginning Java, before moving on to relatively advanced concepts like exporting/executing a JAR.

Comment: Thank you, the link helped.